# how to set sublime text the same with notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, sublimetext2

how to set sublime text the same with notepad++ ?

I have using notepad++ for years, I am be accustomed to notepad++'s default color theme. I had tried to code in sublime under other color themes , but seems hard for me to do that ,other color themes are confusing me, I can not suit them.

I don't want to config a color theme of sublime by myself, for I am working bettween different computers, any themes let sublime the same with notepad++?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of [these color schemes](https://github.com/daylerees/colour-schemes?hn).  There is also a color scheme editor [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=9856).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a something related to that
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/63627

I think it should be something like this in particular theme file

```
<key>selection</key>
<string>#hexcolor</string>
```

Color codes from here: http://html-color-codes.com/